# Hibernate persist is inserting without transaction commit

Tags: java, hibernate

When this code runs

```
try(Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession())
{
   Transaction trans = session.beginTransaction();
   session.persist(venue);
```

the entity is inserted without calling `trans.commit();` . The logs show

> Hibernate: insert into venue_users etc.....

Any ideas why this is happening?

My HibernateUtil class

```
     private static StandardServiceRegistry registry;
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if (sessionFactory == null) {
            try {
                // Create registry
                registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure().build();
                // Create MetadataSources
                MetadataSources sources = new MetadataSources(registry);
                // Create Metadata
                Metadata metadata = sources.getMetadataBuilder().build();
                // Create SessionFactory
                sessionFactory = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                if (registry != null) {
                    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
                }
            }
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }
    public static void shutdown() {
        if (registry != null) {
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
        }
    }
```

Hibernate.cfg (without entities/personal info)

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sof?serverTimezone=UTC&amp;useLegacyDatetimeCode=false;</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
    
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
</session-factory>
```

Comment: What's the ID generation strategy of the entity?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli `@Id

 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

 private int id;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contract of the method `persist` is that after calling the method the ID of the entity must be set.

If you have `GenerationType.IDENTITY` then the only possible solution is to execute the insert statement to get the auto increment value from the database.

That's why you see the insert statement.

Comment: Thanks, how would I reverse the insert - say if I persisted the above, did some additional work then due to an error it needs to be removed? I tried using `trans.rollback();` but I presume since no transaction had been committed nothing was removed

Comment: If the transaction is not committed nothing is stored in the database

Comment: It is in the database, logs show insert and the database also shows the new row. I can't understand why it is doing this because I don't recall having behaviour like this in the past.

Comment: So you can see the record after the application is stopped? Do you have auto commit enabled? How do you create the connection?

Comment: Yes, I noticed the issue in debug mode going through line by line. As soon as the persist happens (on any entity type) it is inserted and the row appears in my db. As far as I'm aware no auto commit is enabled. I have added my hibernate.cfg showing connection info in the post

Comment: it's correct that the insert statement is executed and if you are in the same transacation you also see the record in the db. But do you also see the record when you look at the database in another connection?

Comment: You can try to disable auto commit: https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/behavior-when-hibernate-connection-autocommit-set-to-false/1614

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229472/discussion-between-tom-and-simon-martinelli).